# Split a string AFTER a pattern occurs

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have the following vector of strings. It contains two elements. Each of the elements is composed by two collapsed phrases.

```
strings <- c("This is a phrase with a NameThis is another phrase",
         "This is a phrase with the number 2019This is another phrase")
```

I would like to split those phrases for each element in the vector. I've been trying something like:

```
library(stringr)

str_split(strings, "\\B(?=[a-z|0-9][A-Z])")
```

which almost gives me what I'm looking for:

```
[[1]]
[1] "This is a phrase with a Nam" "eThis is another phrase"

[[2]]
[1] "This is a phrase with the number 201" "9This is another phrase"
```

I would like to make the split AFTER the pattern but cannot figure out how to do that.

I guess I'm close to a solution and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to match the position *right before* the capital letters, not the position before the last letter of the initial phrase (which is one character before the position you need). You might just match a non-word boundary with lookahead for a capital letter:

```
str_split(strings, "\\B(?=[A-Z])")
```

If the phrases can contain leading capital letters, but do not contain any capital letters after the lowercase letters start, you can split them as well with lookbehind for a digit or a lowercase letter. No non-word boundary needed this time:

```
strings <- c("SHOCKING NEWS: someone did somethingThis is another phrase",
         "This is a phrase with the number 2019This is another phrase")
str_split(strings, "(?<=[a-z0-9])(?=[A-Z])")
```

Comment: That is great! Thanks! I did not put this example but what if I have a string such as "SHOCKING NEWS: someone did somethingThis is another phrase"? Could you give a general example which would also produce the expected result in this case?

Comment: Thank you again. I really appreciate your help. I wish I could upvote your answer one more time.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative solution. Look for a lowercase letter or digit followed by an uppercase letter, and split in-between.

```
strsplit(strings, "(?<=[[:lower:][:digit:]])(?=[[:upper:]])", perl=TRUE)

[[1]]
[1] "This is a phrase with a Name" "This is another phrase"      

[[2]]
[1] "This is a phrase with the number 2019" "This is another phrase"
```